# Herkunft der Redewendung "Das Gegenteil von 'gut' ist 'gut gemeint'."

Tags: etymology, phrase

Zur Bedeutung: Des Öfteren versuchen Menschen anderen zu helfen, indem sie nicht das tun, was sie sollten/man von ihnen erwartet hat, sondern etwas ihrer Meinung nach besser Geeignetes. Wenn sie anschließend mit einem Misserfolg konfrontiert werden, kommen dann Phrasen wie "ich hab' es doch nur gut gemeint". Insofern kann "Das Gegenteil von 'gut' ist 'gut gemeint'." als Antwort darauf verstanden werden. Unabhängig von der Intention ist das Ergebnis schlecht.

Zur Herkunft: In meinen aktiven Sprachschatz habe ich das Wort erst vor wenigen Jahren übernommen, gehört vermutlich gegen 2000 zum ersten Mal. Neulich habe ich diese Wendung in einer Folge "Büro, Büro" (Folge 20, vermutlich von 1982) wiederentdeckt. Ich hätte nicht gedacht, dass diese Wendung schon so alt, möglicherweise sogar älter ist. Ältere Quellen konnte ich bisher nicht finden.

Daher nun die Frage: Was ist der Ursprung der Redewendung "Das Gegenteil von 'gut' ist 'gut gemeint'."?

Comment: Der Anfang trifft es m.E. nicht. Ob man das von einer Person erwartet hat, oder etwas anderes, ist nicht der Punkt, sondern ob es wie erwünscht gewirkt hat.

Comment: @user unknown - Entweder hat nichts erwartet, im Sinne von "nicht eingreifen"/"nicht stören" oder aber man hat eine bestimmte Handlung erwartet. Wie du aber schon gesaagt hast, ist das aber eher unwichtig in relation zum Rest.

Comment: Ein Wähler kann von Frau Merkel erhoffen, eine ultimative Lösung der Eurokrise zu bewirken, ohne eine Vorstellung über das geeignete `wie` zu haben, und dann, nach Scheitern derartiger Versuche, enttäuscht feststellen, diese seien gut gemeint gewesen.

Comment: @user unknown bei diesem konkreten Problem kann ich dir zwar nicht ganz folgen (ob die Maßnahmen überhaupt gut gemeint sind, oder bloß die Lage des anderen verschlechtern sollen)  abstrahiert gesehen aber zustimmen: Person M erklärt P zum Problem und tut T. Das Ergebnis wird als Fehlschlag anerkannt und die Tat T als immerhin gut gemeint dargestellt.

Comment: @mbx: Auch das trifft es aber meiner Meinung nach noch nicht. Dass ein gutgemeinter Versuch nicht die erhoffte Verbesserung bringt, kommt schließlich ständig vor (es kann ja nicht alles klappen) - meines Erachtens zu häufig, als dass man es durch eine Redewendung kommentieren müsste. Wenn nun aber T statt einer Verbesserung eine *Verschlechterung* der Situation herbeiführt, dann ist der hier genannte Spruch angebracht.

Comment: vielleicht ist es eine Verdrehung von Goethes Faust: (ich glaube es zwar selber nicht, aber es könnte ja sein, zumindest eine Anspielung daran) "Teil von jener Kraft,
die stets das Gute will und stets das Böse schafft"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Diese Redewendung ist ein Zitat und lautet vollständig:

> Das Gegenteil von *gut* ist nicht *böse*, sondern *gut gemeint*.

Es ist eine Abwandlung eines Zitats des Dichters [Gottfried Benn (1886-1956)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gottfried_Benn). Benns Originalzitat ist als Warnung an politisch engagierte Kunst zu verstehen und lautet:

> Kunst ist das Gegenteil von *gut gemeint*.

Im Internet und in Büchern werden zwei verschiedene Personen als Urheber der Abwandlung genannt:

1. [Kurt Tucholsky (1890-1935)](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurt_Tucholsky)
2. [Bertold Brecht (1889-1956)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertolt_Brecht)

Ich kann leider nicht mit Sicherheit sagen, wer von beiden die Wendung früher verwendet hat.

[Bei Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_gefl%C3%BCgelter_Worte/G#Gut_gemeint_ist_das_Gegenteil_von_gut.) gibt es noch einige zusätzliche Informationen zum Thema.

Comment: Im Wikipedia-Artikel wird auch Voltaire angeführt - der wäre zumindest mit der sinngemäß gleichen Wendung noch etwas früher gewesen.

Comment: @ladybug Voltaires Zitat lautet *„Das Bessere ist der Feind des Guten“* – ich finde, das ist doch etwas zu weit entfernt.

Comment: Hmh, ja, kann man sich streiten... bei der Frage nach der "Herkunft" ist es sicherlich legitim, auch den Inhalt und nicht nur die konkrete Wendung zu betrachten. Was ich aber nicht ganz verstehe: wo hast du denn her, dass das "Originalzitat" das von Gottfried Benn sei? Auf Wikipedia wird das nur als Variante aufgeführt?

Comment: @ladybug Dass das Zitat über die Kunst von Gottfried Benn ist m. E. unbestritten. Lässt sich schnell im Internet verifizieren. Es gibt viele Quellen, z. B. http://www.literaturkritik.de/public/rezension.php?rez_id=9727&ausgabe=200607 (letzter Absatz)

Comment: Das meinte ich nicht. Du schreibst oben: "Es ist eine Abwandlung eines Zitats des Dichters Gottfried Benn " - aber woher weißt du, dass es nicht umgekehrt ist? Also das Zitat von Gottfried Benn eine Abwandlung des ersten Zitats?

Comment: @ladybug ja, das könnte auch sein. Habe auch nach längerem Recherchieren nicht herausgefunden, welche Wendung zuerst da war. Henne und Ei sozusagen.

Comment: @ladybug [Hier](http://de.rec.buecher.narkive.com/cd2oAulj/zitatsuche-das-gegenteil-von-kunst) nennt jemand den "Roman des Phänotyp" als Quelle des Benn-Zitats. [Laut Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gottfried_Benn#Zum_Werk) hat er den seit 1943 geschrieben und 1949 veröffentlicht. Da war Tucholsky schon lange tot. Und so oft, wie ihm das Zitat aus der Frage zugeschrieben wird, glaube ich zumindest, dass es schon zu seinen Lebzeiten im Umlauf war. Das spricht für mich dafür, dass Benn das in der Frage genannte Zitat abgewandelt hat und nicht umgekehrt.

Answer (score 10):

Wer auch immer der Urheber ist, er wurde wohl inspiriert von

> The road to hell is paved with good intentions.

Dieser Spruch wird [Samuel Johnson](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_Johnson) (1709–1784) zugeschrieben.

Comment: @userunknown Ich hab mal die Lebensdaten ergänzt. Zu dem Satz gibt es einen [eigenen Wikipedia-Artikel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_road_to_hell_is_paved_with_good_intentions), demzufolge der Spruch seinerseits wieder inspiriert wurde von Bernhard Clairvaux ("L'enfer est plein de bonnes volontés et désirs" - "Die Hölle ist voll guter Absichten und Wünsche"), und der wiederum von Virgil und dem Neuen Testament - es scheint im Kern ein sehr alter Gedanke zu sein.

Comment: Auch wenn hier eine Inspiration vorliegen mag, ist dennoch zu beachten, dass die genannte deutsche Redewendung i.A. auf andere Szenarien angewandt wird als die hier genannte englische.

Answer (score 5):

Wie @splattne schon richtig geschrieben hat, lautet das Zitat vollständig

> Das Gegenteil von *gut* ist nicht *böse*, sondern *gut gemeint*.

Neben Brecht und Tucholsky wird manchmal auch [Erich Kästner](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erich_K%C3%A4stner) (1899 - 1974) als Urheber genannt und häufiger [Karl Kraus](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Kraus) (1874 - 1936). Nirgendwo habe ich aber eine genaue Quellenangabe dazu gefunden.

Bei Kästner würde ich eher eine Verwechslung vermuten mit seinem Spruch

> Es gibt nichts Gutes, außer: man tut es. <sup>Quelle: *Moral* in: Doktor Erich Kästners Lyrische Hausapotheke</sup>

Von Karl Kraus wiederum stammt der Spruch

> Das Übel gedeiht nie besser, als wenn ein Ideal davorsteht. <sup>aus: [Aphorismen](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/aphorismen-4692/1)</sup>

Der liegt von der Idee her schon recht nah dran. Er wäre als Urheber des gesuchten Zitats damit sicher plausibel, aber ebenso könnte gerade das die Ursache für eine fälschliche Zuschreibung sein.

Auch Kraus formuliert wandelt dabei aber nur eine ältere Idee ab (hier zuerst von @marton78 eingebracht):

> The road to hell is paved with good intentions.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_road_to_hell_is_paved_with_good_intentions) nennt dazu mehrere mögliche Urheber und führt die Linie noch weiter zurück ins 11. Jh. zu Bernhard Clairvaux ("L'enfer est plein de bonnes volontés et désirs" - "Die Hölle ist voll guter Absichten und Wünsche"), zu Virgil und ins Neue Testament.

@splattne hat auf Gottfried Benn hingewiesen. Laut [diesem Blog-Post](http://www.damaschke.de/notizen/index.php/gut-gemeint-2/) lautet dessen Version

> Wo gedacht wird, fühlt sich das Deutschtum bereits verraten; wo aber vollends Kunst endemisch auftritt, schickt es die Apotheker an die Front. Ein feiner Instinkt übrigens! Es hat sich allmählich herumgesprochen, daß der Gegensatz von Kunst nicht Natur ist, sondern gut gemeint; Stil ist eine bösartige Neubildung, eine letale.

Als Quelle wird dort genannt: "Gottfried Benn: Roman des Phänotyp (1944); gegen Ende des Abschnitts “Statische Metaphysik”; in: Gesammelte Werke, hg. v. Dieter Wellershof, Frankfurt a.M: Zweitausendeins 2003, Band 2, S. 1333 f.", damit stammt dieses Zitat aus einer Zeit, als Kraus und Tucholsky schon tot waren.

Wie wir gesehen haben, ist die Grundidee, daß gute Absichten böse Folgen haben können, deutlich älter. Benn äußert sich in ähnlicher Weise speziell zum Verhältnis von Kunst und Natur. Sein Zitat ist die einzige belegte Quelle, in der die Formulierung "gut gemeint" und die Zuspitzung auf einen vermeintlichen Gegensatz verwendet wird, aber es ist eindeutig nicht der gesuchte Ausspruch. Es wäre theoretisch denkbar, dass Brecht oder ein Unbekannter diesen Spruch aufgegriffen und zu dem gesuchten Zitat verallgemeinert hat. Wahrscheinlicher erscheint mir aber die Vermutung, dass der gesuchte Satz in den 20er / 30er Jahren des 20. Jahrhunderts von Brecht, Kraus, Tucholsky oder einem hinter diesen Namen verblassenden Unbekannten geprägt wurde und von Benn für sein Buch abgewandelt wurde.

Comment: super! das ist wohl   in Teil von jener Kraft,
die stets das Gute will und stets das Böse schafft